# Excel - Index function with 2 arrays inside reference

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing

a guy in my department wrote this complicated formula that I dont really understand how the function worked, hope you could help me understand. The function is written as below

```
=SUMPRODUCT((GLs=$B9)* INDEX(Ops INDIRECT(D$5),,)*(Periods=Period))/1000
```

The part that I dont understand is the INDEX part. Inside the reference for the array, this guy put 2 arrays inside it with one array bigger than the other. When I used the evaluate formula, it return as below of the index function (I only show the effect on INDEX formula)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((GLs=$B9)* INDEX('Ops Asia'!$F$7:$BV$38 'Ops Asia'!$AV$7:$BG$545,,)*(Periods=Period))/1000
```

One more step of evaluation will return the INDEX formula as below

```
=SUMPRODUCT((GLs=$B9)* INDEX('Ops Asia'!$AV$7:$BG$38,,)*(Periods=Period))/1000
```

It seems that by putting 2 arrays inside the reference part of INDEX function, a smaller array is returned. I have never heard about this use of INDEX function and hope someone can help explain to me how this mechanism work and is there any online resource mentioning about this use of nested arrays?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

INDEX is being used to provide the intersection of the two ranges. An easier to understand example might be,

```
=SUM(INDEX(A:C 5:7, , ))
```

The Intersection (i.e. overlapping cells) of columns A:C and rows 5:7 would be A5:C7. Note that INDEX is being used in its array form with no row or column numbers provided (although they need to be represented by blanks, hence the extra commas).

I'm not sure if INDEX is absolutely required as `=SUM(A:C 5:7)` does the same thing. Its use may have just been an easy way to include the intersection into the SUMPRODUCT formula.

Comment: IMHO the formula _would_ give the same result without the `INDEX` ie `=SUMPRODUCT((GLs=$B9)* (Ops INDIRECT(D$5))*(Periods=Period))/1000`